# Getting password prompt after editing sudoers file in cent OS 7?

Tags: centos, root, sudoedit

Part of my sudoers file lines begingin with mukesh are edited:

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
mukesh  ALL=(ALL)       SOFTWARE,DRIVERS
mukesh  ALL=(root)      NOPASSWD: /home/mukesh/Desktop/connect.sh
```

permissions of connect.sh

pwd

```
/home/mukesh/Desktop
```

ls -lrt connect.sh

```
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 47 Apr  4 20:07 connect.sh
```

**cat connect.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo pppoe-start
```

I just want to run connect.sh as root without any prompts

EDIT :

```
[mukesh@centos Desktop]$ ./connect.sh
pppoe-start: You must be root to run this script
[mukesh@centos Desktop]$ sudo ./connect.sh
[sudo] password for mukesh: 
[mukesh@centos Desktop]$ su -
Password: 
Last login: Mon Apr  4 10:27:09 IST 2016 on pts/0
[root@centos ~]# pwd
/root
[root@centos ~]# cd /home/mukesh
[root@centos mukesh]# cd Desktop
[root@centos Desktop]# ./connect.sh
. Connected!
[root@centos Desktop]# 



[mukesh@centos Desktop]$ cat connect.sh
#!/bin/bash
pppoe-start
[mukesh@centos Desktop]$ sudo /home/mukesh/Desktop/connect.sh
[sudo] password for mukesh: 
. Connected!
```

[Here is my full sudoers file](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/2KBJ)

Tried removing the permissions using sudo chmod o-x connect.sh

```
-rwxr-xr--.  1 root    root          97 Apr  5 09:30 connect.sh
[mukesh@centos Desktop]$ 
[mukesh@centos Desktop]$ sudo /home/mukesh/Desktop/connect.sh
[sudo] password for mukesh: 
. Connected!
```

EDIT2 :

```
[mukesh@centos Desktop]$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Answer (score 2):

You have set `NOPASSWD` for the script `/home/mukesh/Desktop/connect.sh`, not anything inside it that requires `sudo` password.

You need to run the script using `sudo`:

```
sudo /home/mukesh/Desktop/connect.sh
```

and then remove `sudo` from the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pppoe-start
```

It it's just a single command then you could just add that command to `sudoers` instead (no need for a separate script):

```
mukesh  ALL=(root)      NOPASSWD: /path/to/pppoe-start
```

Also note that setting SETUID bit on script (interpreted executables) won't work.

---

You also have another problem which is you have executable bit set for others i.e. any user can execute the file hence you are being asked for `sudo` password as the general permissions will be preceded by special ones like `sudo`.

So you can remove the execute permissions for others:

```
sudo chmod o-x /home/mukesh/Desktop/connect.sh
```

and now `sudo` should not ask the password.

Comment: heemayl, I am still unable to get it to work as a normal user.i removed the setuid bits and sudo  from the script as u suggested

Comment: @munish run the script as `sudo`: `sudo /home/mukesh/Desktop/connect.sh`

Comment: `[mukesh@centos Desktop]$ sudo ./connect.sh
[sudo] password for mukesh:` yes i tried it promtps me with that as well

Comment: am i editing the sudoers correctly.is it supposed to be on a different line

Comment: @munish No, you have used full path in `sudoers` so you need to use full path i.e. run `sudo /home/mukesh/Desktop/connect.sh` ..shortcut like `sudo ./foobar.sh` won't work..

Comment: OOps, still i get prompt :-) `[mukesh@centos Desktop]$ sudo /home/mukesh/Desktop/connect.sh
[sudo] password for mukesh:`

Comment: @munish found it..check my edits..

Comment: Sorry it did not work, i tried removing for others and others and group.doesn't work

Comment: @munish Do you have any special permissions set e.g. `selinux`?

Comment: i dont think so, how do i check that

Comment: @munish Check the output of `sestatus`

Comment: yes it seems enabled, i added it to my question.Just now read that the dot et the end of `-rwsr-xr-x.` represent that

Comment: @munish Lets have a check..open the file `/etc/selinux/config` and change to `SELINUX=disabled` ..then try again

Comment: its disabled now i even restarted the machine after that to take effect but it doesn't work.I still get the prompt and i see a dot at the end of `-rwxr-xr--.` i dont know if it is because of selinux

Comment: @munish Ok..enable `selinux` now..sorry, thats my limit :)